# How to obtain data from Canvas API?

Tags: canvas-lms

I want to obtain data through canvas API from a moodle course that our institute is doing right now. I went through the documentation and I have generated an access token as advised in the [API documentation](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html). But now I don't know how to proceed.

I tried different examples in the chrome browser console.

ex: GET https:///login/oauth2/auth?  client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/oauth_complete&state=YYY

But it didn't provide me any result. Instead I got errors such as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Can someone please tell me where should I start?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code or a demo page?

Comment: I was following the API documentation. https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate an Access Token by going to "Account -> Settings -> New Access Token" Then copy down the access token.

Then you can make api calls by either

Attaching that access token to your request as a header `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" 'http://<canvas>/api/v1/accounts/<account_id>/courses`

or

Attaching the access token as a GET query parameter

`http://<canvas>/api/v1/accounts/<account_id>/courses?access_token=token_of_magical_powers`

Beware that the access token has all of the same privileges as the user for whom it was generated, so keep it guarded.

More documentation and examples can be found in the [canvas community pages.](https://community.canvaslms.com/docs/DOC-10797-421441247)